# Jest test Error: Cannot parse /myProj/public/libs/angularjs-datetime-picker/package.json

Tags: jestjs

When running my test which uses jest i get the error given in title. 
I have added my public folder in coveragePathIgnorePatterns of jest config but still the same error is being thrown and exit the test with an exitStatus of 1.

Answer (score 0):

if somebody ever runs into this make sure your there are no error in the file. In my case there was a synatax error in the package.json when i removed it everthing started working fine :)